# Delete everything not matching this pattern 'something.swf' in txt file

Tags: text-processing

Can `sed` or `awk` do this? What I want do to is delete everything not matching this pattern `'(something).swf'`

It doesn't need to be these commands, and I'm kind of new. The text processing is via the terminal so I would prefer if it didn't just display the output but saved it to a text file.

#### Example.

On an input like:

```
Hey stackoverflow im 23 years old 'lol.swf' and '33.swf'
```

It should output:

```
'lol.swf'
'33.swf'
```

Comment: Do you mean every line containing this pattern, or delete the actual pattern leaving the rest of the line. Also, does the removal string include the quotes?

Comment: I mean delete everything that is not `'something.swf'`
Example:

`Hey stackoverflow im 23 years old 'lol.swf' and '33.swf'`

would become

`'lol.swf'` `'33.swf'`

Yes, it includes `'`x2

Comment: If anyone knows how, I'd love to see a simple `sed` or `awk` version too. Something like `sed -n "s/.*\('[^']*\.swf'\).*/\1/p"` works, but fails on multiple matches in a single line.

Answer (score 4):

I would just use grep (here assuming GNU `grep`):

```
grep -o "'[^']*\.swf'" input.txt > output.txt
```

#### Explanation

- `-o` prints only the matching part, not the whole line.
- `"'[^']*\.swf'"` is the pattern to match, enclosed in `"` so that you can have `'` in it. It matches an initial `'`, followed by `[^']*`, which is an indeterminate number of non-`'` characters, followed by `.swf` (N.B. you have to escape the `.` as `\.`, since `.` has a special meaning in regular expressions.
- `input.txt` is the input file to read.
- `> output.txt` will redirect output to this file. If you remove this part you can preview the output on the screen.

---

### Alternative

If GNU `grep` isn't installed, you can try the following (inspired by terdon's [replacement](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149270/18887) idea).

```
tr -d '\n' <input.txt | tr "'" '\n' | head -n -1 | tail -n +2 | grep '.*\.swf$' > output.txt
```

#### Explanation

- `tr -d '\n' <input.txt` will read from `input.txt`, then remove all line breaks (`\n`).
- `tr "'" '\n'` will convert all `'` into line breaks. This means that each line was previously surrounded by `'`.
- `head -n -1 | tail -n +2`. However, if the original text file started with `something.swf'` or ended with `'something.swf`, these would be on their own line, despite only having one `'`, and would be erroneously detected by the following `grep`. If, however, the first or last string correctly had both quotes, there would be an extra line break at the beginning or end at this stage. Hence, this segment of code strips off the last line and first line to only match this scenario.
- `grep '\.swf$'` will match lines that end with `.swf`.

Comment: sorry, looks like I edited at the same time as you...

Comment: Ha, no worries @StéphaneChazelas. Thanks for the edit, too. :)

Comment: Glad to help @user3922897. Have a read up on regular expressions if you get a chance. They are truly wonderful!

Comment: @user3922897 If this answer solves your issue please take a minute and click the check mark under the vote count to the left, instead of leaving a thank you comment. This will [signify to everyone](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) that your issue's been resolved and is the way that thanks are expressed in the site.

Answer (score 3):

If your `grep` doesn't support `-o`, you can use `perl` instead:

```
perl -lne "print for /'.*?\.swf'/g" < in.txt > out.txt
```

With `sed`:

```
sed -n "/\('[^']*\.swf'\)/{s//\n\1\n/;s/.*\n\(.*\n\)/\1/;P;D;}"
```

Which is the equivalent of:

```
awk '
  {
    while(match($0, '"/'[^']*\.swf'/"')) {
      print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
      $0 = substr($0, RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
  }'
```

(`D` in `sed` loops with the first line of the pattern space removed).

Comment: Wow, nice `sed`… Could you possibly explain what's going on? +1

Answer (score 2):

Here's an `awk` approach:

```
$ awk "{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(\$i~/'[^']*.swf'/){print \$i}}}" file
'lol.swf'
'33.swf'
```

And a non-GNU grep one. Just change all spaces to newlines and use normal `grep`:

```
$ sed 's/ /\n/g' file | grep "'[^']*.swf'"
'lol.swf'
'33.swf'
```

Comment: +1 Nice one! Could you possibly explain the `awk` code? Good idea with the `grep` too. (FWIW it's slightly faster to use `tr`. `$ time for i in {1..1000} ; do sed 's/ /\n/g' file > /dev/null; done` vs. `$ time for i in {1..1000} ; do tr ' ' '\n' <file > /dev/null; done` for me is 3.108s vs. 1.451s.)

Comment: That assumes they are blank separated though (wouldn't work on `'a.swf','b.swf'`  for instance).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas indeed. It assumes each is a separate word.

Comment: Could you break on `'` instead, then insert it back after the grep?

Comment: I added an alternative inspired by your sed idea, breaking on `'`.